# Using 'datetime64[ns]' format for extraction from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has elements as:

```
df1[1:4]
                   Sims
2014-01-02  [51, 53, 51, 3...
2014-01-03  [56, 48, 64, ...
2014-01-04  [57, 45, 47, ...
```

The sims are list of 500 elements each.

I have another dataframe as:

```
df2[1:4]
                          Date  Month  Day   HE    Year
DateTime                                               
2012-01-01 02:00:00 2012-01-01    1.0  1.0  2.0  2012.0
2012-01-01 03:00:00 2012-01-01    1.0  1.0  3.0  2012.0
2012-01-01 04:00:00 2012-01-01    1.0  1.0  4.0  2012.0
```

I am trying the following in various configurations:

```
df1[df2['Date']]
```

But it errors out complaining about time format difference between `df1` index and `df2['Date']`. However, both have same time format as shown below.

```
df1.index[1:4]
DatetimeIndex(['2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-04'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)


    df2['Date'][1:4].values
array(['2012-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2012-01-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2012-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

How do I make the following work:

```
df1[df2['Date']]
```

Edit:
Error message:

```
KeyError: "['2012-01-01T00:00:00.000000000' '2012-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'\n '2012-01-01T00:00:00.000000000' ..., '2016-12-31T00:00:00.000000000'\n '2016-12-31T00:00:00.000000000' '2016-12-31T00:00:00.000000000'] not in index"
```

Comment: Could you add the actual error message to your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df1[df2['Date']]` -type indexing tends to error in my experience if you are trying to index on rows instead of columns. The problem is presumably that you let `pandas` guess over which axis you whish to slice, and this doesn't always pan out as desired.

You could try using a more explicit indexing method such as `df1.loc[df2['Date'], :]` or `df1.xs(df2['Date'], 0)`.